# Vercel Storage -- @vercel/postgres-kysely

Tags: postgresql, next.js, vercel, next.js13

I'm facing an issue when trying to insert data into my PostgreSQL table from my Next 13 application webhook that accepts a POST request deployed to Vercel.

Database Schema:

```
sql
Copy code
Column_name        Data_type
---------------------------
id                 integer
account_id         character varying
event_data         jsonb
event_timestamp    timestamp without time zone
uri                text
name               text
status             text
start_time         timestamp without time zone
end_time           timestamp without time zone
event_type         text
email              text
rescheduleUrl      text
utmSource          text
cancelUrl          text
```

Error Message:

```
[Error:Webhook] error: invalid input syntax for type integer: "user_2WJPAx618kDIHX66pITbyuvfdz8"
```

I've verified the schema and the utmSource column is of type text, so it should accept the string value. The error suggests a type mismatch, but I can't pinpoint where this is happening.

Here's a snippet of my insertion logic:

```
type InsertableCalendlyEvent = {
    email: string | null;
    account_id: string | null;
    event_data: Json;
    uri: string;
    name: string;
    status: string;
    start_time: Timestamp;
    end_time: Timestamp;
    event_type: string;
    rescheduleUrl: string | null;
    utmSource: string | null;
    cancelUrl: string | null;
}

export async function createCalendlyEvent(calendlyEventData: InsertableCalendlyEvent): Promise<number> {
    const db = getDbInstance();
  
    const insertedCalendlyEvent = await db.insertInto('calendly_events')
        .values(calendlyEventData)
        .returning('id')
        .executeTakeFirstOrThrow();
  
    return insertedCalendlyEvent.id;
}
```

I've already tried clearing the cache on Vercel, checked the database schema by connecting to it, and validated the data before inserting. The same logic seems to work fine locally.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide some insights into what might be causing this?

Comment: Can you run this to check the types of every column `calendly_events` table?
`SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'calendly_events';` I am guessing (account_id) is integer not `string` the issue with datatypes since there is no way to replicate this. And if it is possible please provide a minimal example so that we can replicate this error maybe on some online psotgres compilers?